# Bottomsheetbehavior with gesture nav on behaves strangely

Tags: android, xml, pixel, gesture, bottom-sheet

Anyone else have issues with bottom sheet behavior in their apps? Specifically concerning peek height when using phones which have gesture navigation enabled?

[image: bottom sheet with gesture nav off]

[image: bottom sheet with gesture nav on]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem in my app, I solved it with custom insets consuming(
[Consuming insets manually](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav#consuming-insets))

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.rootView) { _, insets ->
        val systemGestureInsets = insets.systemGestureInsets
        WindowInsetsCompat.Builder()
            .setSystemWindowInsets(insets.systemWindowInsets)
            .setSystemGestureInsets(systemGestureInsets).build()
    }
...
}
```

Comment: now working in android 11